# How to clean pulp collector of a fruit juice extractor

Tags: cleaning, juice, juicing

Not sure if my problem is directly related to home improvement, but this problem at home is making trouble for me.

I have a New Life juice extractor of model FJU-30W-310 which has a pulp collector like this:

[image: pulp collector]

The pulp collector is beneath a rotating disk. The problem is I cannot find a way to take out the collector to wash it with water. Does anybody know how to clean this device make and model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before migrating the question to cooking.SE, someone commented on the home-improvement.SE like this:

[image: comment on home improvement]

That comment was true. I pull off the rotating center part a bit and it just came out of its plastic lock system. Locking system looks like this:

[image]